# Count Duplicate Records from table

Tags: sql

I have the below records in table.

[image: I have the below records in table.]

Need Output in Below format.

[image: Output]

Comment: Presumably, you want `GROUP BY`.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You need simple aggregation, see [Aggregates](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-aggregate-functions/)

```
select HatchNumber, DechNumber, DisPort, Pack,
  sum(ctn_qty) ctn_qty, count(*) TotalRecords
from T
group by HatchNumber, DechNumber, DisPort, Pack
```

Answer (score 0):

To count number of records you can use `group by` clause with the column names you are counting for duplication and `count()` to count the number of rows for same values in those columns. To get the sum of ctn_qty you need to use another aggregate function `sum(ctn_qty)`:

```
select hatchnumber, dechnumber, disport, pack , sum(ctn_qty) ctn_qty, count(*) totalrecords
from mytable 
group by hatchnumber, dechnumber, disport, pack , ctn_qty
```

If you want to have count for only those records which are duplicate then you need to use `having` clause:

```
select hatchnumber, dechnumber, disport, pack ,sum(ctn_qty) ctn_qty, count(*) totalrecords
from mytable 
group by hatchnumber, dechnumber, disport, pack, ctn_qty
having count(*)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have named the table as **practiceTable** . Hope this will work for your desire output.

```
SELECT HatchNumber,DeckNumber,DisPort, pack, 
SUM(ctn_qty) as ctn_qty,     
COUNT(HatchNumber) as TotalRecords
FROM practiceTable
GROUP BY HatchNumber,DeckNumber,DisPort, pack
```